# Will Laravel queue worker exit mid execution with --max-time?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-artisan, supervisord

In [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#processing-jobs-for-a-given-number-of-seconds), it states that `--max-time` will `instruct the worker to process jobs for the given number of seconds and then exit`. I suppose this timer starts when the queue worker is active right? In that case, if my max-time is 600 seconds, at 600 seconds mark, if there's still a job being processed, will the worker still immediately quit or it will wait for the job to finish before quitting?

Comment: reading the docs, i suppose that it will stop the process and if there is a job in queue it will NOT be executed

Answer (score 0):

It will wait for the job to finish before quitting.

In [this post](https://divinglaravel.com/avoiding-memory-leaks-when-running-laravel-queue-workers), Mohamed shows an example for this artisan call utilizing the `--max-time` parameter:

```
php artisan queue:work --max-jobs=1000 --max-time=3600
```

"This worker will automatically exit after processing 1000 jobs or after running for an hour. After processing each job, the worker will check if it exceeded max-jobs or max-time and then decide between exiting or picking up more jobs. **The worker will not exit while in the middle of processing a job.**"

I am using this to avoid memory leaks in the queue workers piling up over time with large jobs.

Answer (score 0):

As [Marco wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73637985/1729441), it will wait for the job to finish before quitting.

This can be confirmed by reading [the source code](https://github.com/illuminate/queue/blob/10.x/Worker.php) for `Illuminate\Queue\Worker`, where `maxTime` is referred to only in `stopIfNecessary`, which is called at the end of each worker loop.

```
    protected function stopIfNecessary(WorkerOptions $options, $lastRestart, $startTime = 0, $jobsProcessed = 0, $job = null)
    {
        return match (true) {
            $this->shouldQuit => static::EXIT_SUCCESS,
            $this->memoryExceeded($options->memory) => static::EXIT_MEMORY_LIMIT,
            $this->queueShouldRestart($lastRestart) => static::EXIT_SUCCESS,
            $options->stopWhenEmpty && is_null($job) => static::EXIT_SUCCESS,
            $options->maxTime && hrtime(true) / 1e9 - $startTime >= $options->maxTime => static::EXIT_SUCCESS,
            $options->maxJobs && $jobsProcessed >= $options->maxJobs => static::EXIT_SUCCESS,
            default => null
        };
    }
```

(If using [Horizon](https://github.com/laravel/horizon/blob/5.x/src/Console/WorkCommand.php), it simply passes the argument to the Laravel queue worker, so the behavior is the same.)